# How to use LMS5xx in ROS?

Tags: ros, laser, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I have a problem to use LMS511.

Is there any kind of package in ROS for LMS511(like hokuyo_node for hokuyo sensor, and sicktoolbox_wrapper for LMS2xx)?

First, I check LMS511 sensor data in windows SOPAS ET software(both Ethernet connection and RS232 connection).

Then, I tried to solve this problem using sicktoolbox_wrapper for LMS511-RS232, but I failed....

I think that my failure may is caused by protocol, packet or ... another something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86246/how-to-use-lms5xx-in-ros?/) by [buljaga](https://answers.ros.org/users/7321/buljaga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buljaga](https://answers.ros.org/users/7321/buljaga/) on 2013-10-02**:
Then, I tried to solve this problem using LMS1xx(http://wiki.ros.org/LMS1xx) for LMS511-Ethernet, but I don't know how to install and how to use...(Is there any tutorial for LMS1xx?)

**Comment by [buljaga](https://answers.ros.org/users/7321/buljaga/) on 2013-10-02**:
Namely my question is.....

```
 1. Is there any kind of package in ROS for LMS511
 2. Could I solve this problem using sicktoolbox_wrapper(how to)?
 3. Could I solve this problem using LMS1xx(how to)?
```

**Comment by [buljaga](https://answers.ros.org/users/7321/buljaga/) on 2013-10-02**:
Please answer me If you know how to solve.

I would appreciate if you could answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately official `sicktoolbox` does not support LMS5xx with Ethernet connectivity. From what you are saying it even looks like it does not support LMS5xx at all.

Nevertheless there is an alternative unofficial version of [laser_drivers with `sicktoolbox2`](https://github.com/rhuitl/laser_drivers), that *does* support it. We had some issues with the version from the trunk though. So here is the [fork](https://bitbucket.org/koreatech-ugv/laser_drivers) of it that we are using at the moment. The changes are minor, but you may want to see the [commit history](https://bitbucket.org/koreatech-ugv/laser_drivers/commits/all).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buljaga](https://answers.ros.org/users/7321/buljaga/) on 2013-10-02**:
Thank you for your answer. :)
Could I ask you more about fork in Korean(personally using the email)?
If you don't mind that...... please email me.(my email is buljaga(at)naver.com)

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-10-02**:
Sorry, I don't speak Korean :) But if you have further questions you can ask them here, on ROS Answers. It is preferable as in this case you will get answers from other people, who can be more experienced than myself. Also other people may find the answers to these question useful.

**Comment by [Rodolfo](https://answers.ros.org/users/17741/rodolfo/) on 2014-05-07**:
Boris. Could you basically explain how to install the sicktoolbox2? I have been trying with no result. I'm new on ROS.

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-02-12**:
Hi, I'm trying to install the sicktoolbox2 but can't find it in the 'apt-get search'. I've tried 'sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-sicktoolbox-wrapper2' but it cannot find it. Please could you show me the command to install this? Could I use 'git clone https://bitbucket.org/koreatech-ugv/l... ?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-02-13**:
@sam-wane, The package is available as source-only. It is a `rosbuild` one ('dry package'), so you have to create [rosbuild workspace overlay](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) in order to compile it. @rodolfo Discovered you 2-year-old comment just now, sorry!

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-02-13**:
Great, I'm getting closer.
I used 'rosmake laser_drivers' although it built 25 with 1 failure.
Still can't run with:
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper2 xxxx
what is the xxxx?
sicklms_5xx?
Sicklms?
sickld?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-02-13**:
You can find all available executables in [CMakeLists.txt](https://bitbucket.org/koreatech-ugv/laser_drivers/src/master/sicktoolbox_wrapper2/ros/sicklms/CMakeLists.txt?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-02-15**:
I tried this:
cd catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/rhuitl/laser_drivers.git
cd ..
rosmake laser_drivers

but there are two failures. When I try:
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper2 sicklms_5xx

I get [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named sicklms_5xx below /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/laser_driv

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-02-15**:
Please create a separate question with detailed information on steps you made and corresponding errors.

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-05-04**:
Ive run:
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper2 sicklms_5xx
but I get the error:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named sicklms_5xx below /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/laser_drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper2

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-05-04**:
I've created a separate question as I think it could be a compile error:
http://answers.ros.org/question/233623/how-to-compile-sicktoolbox_wrapper2/